# Calculation of value of Pi up to 'n' decimal places

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, pi

I was trying to make a C++ program to calculate value of Pi up to 'n' decimal places using the [Leibniz formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80)

The number 'n' would be entered by the user.
I was successful in creating the Leibniz formula but I am having trouble with the latter part i.e value precise up to 'n' places.

The trouble :-
As more and more terms will continue to add to it, it's digits will keep on changing so how to tell if a particular digit has stopped changing despite the addition of more terms.

The code written so far :-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float s=0;
    int w=-1;
    for(float i=1;;i=i+2)
    {
        w=w*(-1);
        s=s+w*(1/i);
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It would be great if things would be kept simple since I am just a beginner at C++.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694877/c-library-for-big-float-numbers

Comment: _"I am having trouble"_ is not a problem description. This question is highly vague and incomplete. Please read the Help Centre to see what you're missing - chiefly, the code you've written so far and a specific problem.

Comment: either I am missing something or the digits changing has nothing to do with pi being transcendental. You could write a (poor) iterative estimation for 1.0 and still have digits changing forever

Comment: Please, expose sample code. Are you aware of numerical floating point issues e.g. [SO: Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100490/7478597)?

Comment: Surely Google is a better place for this? This problem has been studied since the 1950s.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  Aside from that, look at `std::setprecision` (in the `<iomanip>` header).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to compute `Pi` up to *arbitrary* `n`th digit, you want a library for working with *big float numbers*; see

[C++ library for big float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694877/c-library-for-big-float-numbers)

the real trouble is that *Leibniz formula* is *not useful* in the context. The actual precision achieved can be estimated as the *last term* in the formula

```
  Pi / 4 = 1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ... + (-1)**(n + 1) * 1 / (2 * n - 1) + ...
```

If, for intance, you want `Pi` up to `100`th digit it means that the residual (and the last term) should be less than `1e-100`:

```
 1 / (2 * n - 1) < 1e-100
 2 * n  - 1 > 1e100
 n > 5e99
```

And as you can see `5e99` *loops* is by far *too much* for the modern (super-)computers

Comment: Just one more thing sir, you mentioned that for accuracy upto 100 digits would mean that the last term must be less than 1e-100. But isn't there a possibility that many of those small terms would add up to increment that last decimal digit?

Comment: @infinitely curious: No, it's known result (theorem) about *alternating series*; so called *alternating series estimation theorem*: the residual is less than the last term.